# Finding the variable

Tags: geometry

[image: This is the work I did.]

I am not sure how to solve number one. I tried figuring it out. I am not sure how you find x first.

Comment: sorry i need help with number 1 :)

Comment: Do you know what complementary angles are?

Comment: Yes they make 90 degrees

Comment: In a right triangle, what must be true about the acute angles?

Comment: They add up to 90 degrees

Comment: That enables you to solve for $x$.  You can use trigonometry to solve for $y$.

Comment: So would x be 37 in that case?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: So then for solving y I would use the Pythagorean theorem right?

Answer (score 1):

To solve for $x$, use the fact that the acute angles of a right triangle are complementary.

You know the length of the leg of the right triangle opposite the $53^\circ$ angle.  Hence,

$$\tan(53^\circ) = \frac{9}{y}$$

Solving for $y$ yields

$$y = \frac{9}{\tan(53^\circ)}$$

Note that you cannot use the Pythagorean Theorem to solve for $y$ since you do not know the length of the hypotenuse.  The segment of length $4$ is the length of the segment of the hypotenuse outside the circle.  Once you determine $y$, you can determine the length of the hypotenuse with the Pythagorean Theorem.

Comment: So then would y= 6.78?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: What is the sum of the angles in a triangle? The other two angles are given.
(the handwritten notes contains half his calculation)

Answer (score 0):

Acute angles of a right triangle=90 degrees, so 90-53=37 X=37